# Android (java): OnBackPress() closes my app when trying to go back from Activity to fragment

Tags: java, android, android-studio

So far I had gone from fragment to the DetailActivity, now I added back button to take me back to the previous fragment. I tried the below code but the app keeps closing instead of going back to the fragment.
Both of these code snippets are from my code.

Fragment.java

```
public class Fragment extends Fragment implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {


    String[] days = {"Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"};
    
    private Button btnNext;
   


    public Fragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        btnNext = view.findViewById(R.id.add);
        btnNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(),
DetailActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        getActivity().onBackPressed();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {

    }
```

And this is my onBackPressed() from DetailActivity.java method:

```
     public void onBackPressed(){
                FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
                if (fm.getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
                    Log.i("DetailActivity", "popping backstack");
                    fm.popBackStack();
                } else {
                    Log.i("DetailActivity", "nothing on backstack, calling super");
                    super.onBackPressed();
                }
            }
```

DetailActivity.java :

```
    public class DeatilActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

   
    
    Button btnBack;
    


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail);

        
       
        btnBack = findViewById(R.id.btnBack);

        btnBack.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
    
                onBackPressed();

            }
        });

    }

  
   /* @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() != 0) {
            getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    } */

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed(){
        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        if (fm.getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
            Log.i("DetailActivity", "popping backstack");
            fm.popBackStack();
        } else {
            Log.i("DeatilActivity", "nothing on backstack, calling super");
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

}
```

Any idea ? :(

Comment: `getSupportFragmentManager()`

Comment: Can you share the code you use to launch the DetailActivity? Actually, also the code to show the initial fragment would be helpful too - i.e. is addToBackStack used there.

Comment: @TheRyanKing87 Hi, I just updated the post

Comment: One observation - why are we calling getActivity().onBackPressed(); right after starting the new activity? It looks like that finishes the current activity, so I wonder if it isn't there for you to go back to later on.

Comment: @TheRyanKing87 OHHH right! I uncommented that part, and it works now!! Thank you!

Comment: Nice! Glad we got there :) I'm going to pop this into an answer - accepting it would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity, calling onBackPressed finishes the current activity, so it won't be there to return to if called from the launching activity. Removing this call seems to fix the issue seen here.

Comment: I have another question now, after i removed the on onBackPressed, it seems to like the update from the detail activity doesn't show right away, whats the issue now :/

Comment: Can you describe what you're seeing a bit further? Is the transition from the fragment to the DetailActivity happening, but with a delay, or is it something else?

Comment: The transition is now happening from DetailActivity to the fragment as I wanted it, but the data is not updated in the fragment, do I need to have another method to reload the page or something?

Comment: Can you clarify what data you're expecting to see in the fragment? Looking at what's in there, I see the array of Strings for days of the week, but I'm not seeing any bundle arguments being passed or any ui besides the button. Has it been updated since the original post?

Comment: Fyi - I'll do my best to help, but it may be worth organizing this issue into another question (& linking to this one for context) to potentially get others' eyes on it may help get to a solution faster.

Comment: Hey, its fine, thank you for trying! I think I got it kinda solved, I just added a reload option in my code so it reloads the fragment when I go back

Comment: Nice! Glad you got there :)